# Jquery returning false - why?

Tags: jquery

I have following example: **[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MKjTL/4/)**

My statement is returning false, why?

```
if( $('.superstars-table tr').slice(5).is(':hidden') == true ){ alert('yes');}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your selector `$('.superstars-table tr').slice(5)` isn't matching any elements. The [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice) method is **zero-indexed**, so try `$('.superstars-table tr').slice(4)` instead.